# Load Data From Server While Scrolling a Div to Bottom

Tags: jquery, javascript

I need to load data inside a div only when I reached near the bottom of the div through scroll.

The problem am facing is the $('div').scrollHeight() and the $('div').scrollTop() values are not same when it reaches the bottom, so I can't identify that the scroll reached the bottom or not.

How can I identify the div scroll have reached near the bottom(or may be bottom minus some length)?

Please advice...

Note: Basically am trying to do the same like in Facebook ticker.

Regards,
Navin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's lots of scroller samples on the web the code below is from [this one](http://cfsilence.com/blog/client/index.cfm/2007/8/21/Ajax-Paging-Through-Records-On-Scroll).

```
...
    if(container.scrollTop+container.clientHeight == container.scrollHeight){
                startRow = parseInt(startRow) + 10;
                getData();
    }
...
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Heres a JSFiddle [scroll](http://jsfiddle.net/wWmqr/1) it uses scrollTop + clientHeight to compare against scrollHeight.  See if that works for you, sorry its in Mootools but it pretty straight forward.

```
function HandleScroll()
{
    var el = $("outer");
    if( (el.scrollTop + el.clientHeight) >= el.scrollHeight )
    {
        el.setStyles( { "background-color": "red"} );
    }
    else
    {
        el.setStyles( { "background-color": "white"} );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you get the document height, and use that height as the length between the top of your page to the bottom. So :

```
var bottom = $(document).height() // == the bottom of your page
```

You can the minus that with the distance with the bottom, that you desire.

```
If( ( el.scrollTop() + el.outherHeight ) >= ( bottom - 200 ) ){
    // fetch new data

    // Don't forget to upate the bottom variable when data fetched and renderd
}
```

Hope this solved your problem, or at least helped you find your solution. If not, let me know